# Not enough space in boot partision for update

Tags: disk-usage

I have a separate partision for /boot. It has the standard size of a normal Ubuntu installation (700+ MB). There are only the latest two kernel versions installed but 50%+ of the space is taken and I can't install the new update from 21.04 to 21.10. I could delete the second kernel but that would only be a temporary fix. I have searched a lot but the solution was always to "delete the dozent old kernel versions". I only have the one I'm using and the backup kernel. Are there other known ways to free up space that I cound'nt find.

df -h

```
Dateisystem               Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
tmpfs                      1,6G    3,6M  1,6G    1% /run
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root  467G    112G  332G   26% /
tmpfs                      7,8G     34M  7,8G    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      5,0M    4,0K  5,0M    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                      4,0M       0  4,0M    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                  705M    353M  302M   54% /boot
/dev/sda1                  511M    5,3M  506M    2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                      1,6G    152K  1,6G    1% /run/user/1000
```

ls -la /boot

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    253064 Sep 17 17:17 config-5.11.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    253112 Sep 20 16:38 config-5.11.0-37-generic
drwx------  3 root root      4096 Jan  1  1970 efi/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root      4096 Okt  2 21:55 grub/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        28 Okt  2 21:54 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.11.0-37-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 157987201 Sep 22 19:03 initrd.img-5.11.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 158725164 Okt  3 17:50 initrd.img-5.11.0-37-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        28 Okt  2 21:54 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.11.0-36-generic
drwx------  2 root root     16384 Feb 20  2020 lost+found/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    182704 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    184380 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    184884 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root   5973530 Sep 17 17:17 System.map-5.11.0-36-generic
-rw-------  1 root root   5973718 Sep 20 16:38 System.map-5.11.0-37-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        25 Okt  2 21:54 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.11.0-37-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  14752320 Sep 17 19:29 vmlinuz-5.11.0-36-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  14757248 Sep 20 17:35 vmlinuz-5.11.0-37-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        25 Okt  2 21:54 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.11.0-36-generic
```

Comment: Your initrd images seem to be 3x the size they are on my system.  That's what's taking up all the room, no idea how that happened.

Comment: PC or Laptop and what type? Try `ls -la /boot/efi` and see what is there. You do not need a separate book partition anymore. Doesn't mean you cannot configure your system that way just if you end up re-installing keep that in mind.

Comment: I deleted the older kernel version and updated successfully my system.The new installed kernel is not that big. It seams like the problem is solved even though I don't know why this happened. My main partition is encrypted. That's the reason why I use a boot partition and could not enlarge it.

Comment: There is a COMPRESS in /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf which is set to lz4 on my system -- check your system, if not set, that explains the larger initrd sizes.

Comment: The value is `zstd` on my system. I will watch the situation and when I have the same problem again I will change this value. Thanks.